# Static Fix and Audio Mic Recognition

Tags: audio

So I didn't find any forums for the product, hopefully anyone here can help.

I recently bought this new headset, the Etekcity H5GX Gaming Headset, link is below, and despite the reviews that say they get no static when using the mic, when I record in Audacity or Audition, there is static. When I try to use the mic on Skype, it doesn't even recognize it. I think there may be something wrong within my settings or sound card, or perhaps I changed something within the sound manager panel that I wasn't supposed to change.

Here are my specs:

Windows 10

Description: Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)

Default Sound Playback: Yes

Default Voice Playback: Yes

Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0269&SUBSYS_17AAC034&REV_1002

Manufacturer ID: 1

Product ID: 100

Type: WDM

Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys

Driver Version: 6.00.0001.7535 (English)

Driver Attributes: Final Retail

WHQL Logo'd: Yes

Date and Size: 6/24/2015 21:57:00, 4504320 bytes

Driver Provider: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

HW Accel Level: Basic

Cap Flags: 0xF1F

Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B012EQG6ZK?refRID=6QZ33FWHEA2WGD2RX61X&ref_=pd_cart_vw_2_1_p](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012EQG6ZK)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Have you contacted [Etekcity](http://www.etekcity.com/article/fdetail.html?cid=35) for support? Some of the product reviews at the link you provided stated problems with Win 10.

Comment: I sent them an e-mail. Kind of sucks, my old headset was cheaper than this one, and it was better quality... This one was more expensive and it's giving me issues... And I can't rollback from Windows 10 because it's been a while since I updated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "static"--is it continuous background noise, or is it an intermittent clicking, or more just a distortion of your voice, like choppiness or rapid cutting in/out?

IMHO the first order of business is to get the mic working in Skype, so you can run some tests.  Skype is pretty finicky, so getting it to work there will be a key step.  Go to Skype>Tools>Options>Audio settings.  Click the little blue triangle on the right side of the window, right next to the Speakers selector.  See if that works right.

Then, look up to the Microphone pick list just above it.  You should have at least two options, try them all.  See if the volume indicator shows anything when you talk into the mic.  See if the volume indicator shows the noise you are hearing.

Go to the Control Panel for audio devices.  Depending on the brand of PC, there may be more than one control system for audio (e.g., Beats audio).  You'll have to do some experimentation because each of these proprietary thingies is  different, but buried in those control panels somewhere is the item you want to click.

If you are offered a "bit rate" or other quality indicator, choose "CD Quality" or "44kHz" or "44100" *but nothing higher*.  That audio quality setting can definitely confuse some apps, even if the hardware can handle it.  If there's a selector for buffer size, choose the largest size on the list.

Sorry I can't be more specific, but there are too many proprietary variables to give you a simple answer.

Comment: Yes it is a constant static buzzing, and I have Lenovo and the RealTek audio driver, I will take a look at your tips though. The only thing I have for Skype in Microphone options is Stereo Mix and Microphone Array.

Comment: God knows where it is hidden, but you want to find the mini control panel for "manage audio devices".  Sometimes, in the actual "device manager" mini control panel, you'll find weird settings down at the lowest level of hardware.

Comment: Of course---before you spend hours on this if you have a DIFFERENT microphone, plug it in to the same mic jack that you are currently trying to use... if the other mic displays the same symptoms, it's something weird in the software OR you have a defective chip inside your PC.  If the other mic works fine, then the culprit is your "new one".  In your audio mixer applet, make sure that all other inputs are turned down so you don't confuse yourself with other sources.  As I said at the beginning, this is one of those awful areas where you just have to experiment.